# php run javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

is it possible to run some javascript expression? for example `echo eval("Math.sqrt('25')");`

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JS on the client. Therefore, no, PHP cannot run JS.

Comment: @nico JS is platform agnostic and therefore can run wherever you want. node.js is a web server that uses JS for scripting. AppJet & jGate are other examples.

Comment: @kim3er: Sure, but if you're echoing the JS, it will run on the client not on the server. Moreover, we have no indication whatsoever that he has access to the server.

Comment: @nico I guess the problem is ambiguity in the question. Kusanagi, what is your intention? To trigger client side script after a page has rendered? Or, to run JS on the server?

Comment: I am pretty sure you could have just tested and found that this works just fine.  You can not use the value in php unless you send it back `server-side` but you can echo emca script that will be run by the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In normal situations :

- PHP runs on the server
- and, then, Javascript is run on the client, in the browser.

So, no, it's not quite possible to have PHP execute some Javascript code on the server.

**But** there is at least on PHP extension that embed *(or wrap arround)* a Javascript engine, and, as a consequence, allows one to execute Javascript on the server, from PHP.

The extension I'm thinking about is the [**spidermonkey**](http://pecl.php.net/package/spidermonkey) one : installing and enabling it on your server will allow you to execute Javascript code, on the server, from PHP.

Of course, like any other PHP extension, you'll need to be admin of your server, in order to install it -- and this one is never installed by default, as it answers a very specific need.

About this extension, I have never seen it used in real situations, and there are not many people who tried it... here are two articles you might want to read :

- [Using JavaScript in PHP with PECL and SpiderMonkey](http://devzone.zend.com/1480/using-javascript-in-php-with-pecl-and-spidermonkey/)
- and [SpiderMonkey : Exécuter du Javascript côté serveur, depuis PHP](http://blog.pascal-martin.fr/post/spidermonkey-javascript-serveur-depuis-php) *(this one is in french, and on my own blog)*

Comment: http://css.dzone.com/articles/running-javascript-inside-php you can use v8 if you have admin rights.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
echo "<script language='javascript'> Math.sqrt('25') </script>"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [J4P5](http://j4p5.sourceforge.net/index.php)

I don't know if it's still maintained but you can always fork it, it's released under the GPL license.

Answer (score 3):

put your php into a hidden div and than call it with javascript

**html / php part**

```
<div id="mybox" style="visibility:hidden;"> echo sqrt(25); </div>
```

**javascript part**

```
var myfield = document.getElementById("mybox");
myfield.visibility = 'visible';
```

now, you can do anything with myfield... like this

```
alert(myfield);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is a server-side scripting language that runs on the server and Javascript is a client-side scripting language that runs in a browser you would have to have the PHP generate Javascript code (the same way it generates HTML) that gets executed after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`echo sqrt(25);`

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqrt.php

Answer (score 0):

Run JavaScript code from PHP

php v8js: https://github.com/phpv8/v8js

```
$v8 = new V8Js;
$v8->executeString("Math.sqrt('25')"); // 5
```

https://github.com/chenos/execjs

```
use Chenos\ExecJs\Context;

$cxt = new Context;
$cxt->eval("Math.sqrt('25')"); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have node installed on your server then you can exec this command with php

```
node a.js
```

and then use the console.log as output.