# Calling a JS function in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I know it`s possible to call javascript functions in php and it has worked but when i try to call checkSecondValue, nothing happens. I have included my variations on calling the function.

Edit: If i try to call it at the bottom without activating the onChange event in the select, it won`t work.

```
<!--<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>

<script src="validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
-->
<?php
    //retrieve all the bris for the drop down
include '../../inc/database.php';
$res = BbqcDatabase::getInstance()->doQuery('SELECT * FROM T_TOURNOI_BRIS');
$str = "<select name='ddlBrisSelected' id='ddlBrisSelected' onChange='checkSecondValue()'>";

$bris = ($_GET['bris']);

if($bris == 4)
{
    $bris2 = "autre";
}

if($bris == null)
{
    $str .= "<option value='' selected></option>";
}
else
{
    $str .= "<option value=''></option>";
}

$i = 0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    if($data['F_BRISID'] == $bris)
    {
        $str .= "<option value='" . $data['F_BRISID'] . "' selected '>" . $data['F_BRISTITLE'] . "</option>";
    }
    else 
    {
        $str .= "<option value='" . $data['F_BRISID'] . "'>" . $data['F_BRISTITLE'] . "</option>";
    }
}

if($bris2 == "autre")
{
    $str .= "<option value='autre' selected>Autre</option>";
}
else
{
    $str .= "<option value='autre'>Autre</option>";
}
$str .= "</select>";

echo $str;

if(is_numeric($bris))
{
    /* echo "<SCRIPT language=\"JavaScript\" SRC=\"validation.js\">checkSecondValue();</SCRIPT>"; */
    /* echo "<script> checkSecondValue();</script>"; */
    /* echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">checkSecondValue();</script>"; */
    /* echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'checkSecondValue();', '</script>'; */
    /* echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>checkSecondValue();</SCRIPT>"; */
}

?>
```

Comment: Where is `checkSecondValue()` defined?

Comment: It's not possible to call JS functions in PHP. Learn what you are actually trying to do before learning how to do it.

Comment: in a seperate js file called validation.js

Comment: Correction, it is possible to tell php to write a javascript function call, but it is impossible to call a javascript function while php is executing. However, since we don't see the `checkSecondValue` signature, we cannot tell you what is wrong.

Comment: can you show us the definition of `checkSecondValue()`?  If you have it working for other functions I'm tempted to think there's something wrong with that function rather than the way you're calling it.

Comment: @David: It looks like you have the code commented out that would load `validation.js`.  Is that how it looks in your actual source?

Comment: here is the source for the function: http://pastebin.com/5J5SGkTb

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121832/php-run-javascript-code

Comment: @mellamokb no, only the code that has worked is uncommented

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call client-side javascript functions from PHP, but you can echo code that makes the client call the function on a specific (client-side) event.

Just look at the generated HTML you get from your PHP, and from there, try to see why checkSecondValue() isn't executed on an onChange event.

Comment: My bad, the onChange event works, it`s the bottom part that doesn`t work

Comment: What bottom part? If you mean the stuff you've commented out at the end of the code, like I said, you cannot call client-side javascript functions from PHP. And like Mellanmokb said in the other answer, don't do actual calls to functions until the entire page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you want your function call to happen only after the page is loaded.  This can be done by embedding the function in the body tag during `onload`:

```
<body onload="checkSecondValue();">
```

The function call is going to execute on the client-side, after the entire page has been processed by PHP.  You can't communicate back-and-forth between JavaScript and PHP during the process of the page.